# JS beginner - functions and DOM, can't figure out my mistake - using DOM for func parameters

Tags: javascript, html

Building a simple pokemon type weakness calculator - Here's the JS + HTML
can't understand why it's not working.

I managed to get it working, using innerHTML after each 'if/else' statement, but I can't understand why this doesn't work.

```js
let type = document.getElementById("type");

let answer = weakness(type); {
  if (type.value === 'fire') {
    return ('Rock, ' + 'Water, ' + 'Ground');
  } else if (type.value === 'water') {
    return ('Grass, ' + 'Electric')
  } else if (type.value === 'grass') {
    return ('Fire, ' + 'Bug, ' + 'Ice, ' + 'Flying')
  }
}

document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = (answer);
```

```html
<p>Type:
  <select id="type" name="type" placeholder="Select type">
    <option value="fire">Fire</option>
    <option value="water">Water</option>
    <option value="grass">Grass</option>
  </select>
  <p><input type="button" value="Calulate" onclick="weakness(type)"></p>

  <p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: Your code in syntactically incorrect. `return` is only valid inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your code mistakes, check out.

```js
let type = document.getElementById("type");

const weakness = (type) => {
  if (type.value === 'fire') {
    return ('Rock, ' + 'Water, ' + 'Ground');
  } else if (type.value === 'water') {
    return ('Grass, ' + 'Electric')
  } else if (type.value === 'grass') {
    return ('Fire, ' + 'Bug, ' + 'Ice, ' + 'Flying')
  }
}

const calcWeakness = () => {
  let answer = weakness(type);
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = answer;
}
```

```html
<p>Type:
  <select id="type" name="type" placeholder="Select type">
    <option value="fire">Fire</option>
    <option value="water">Water</option>
    <option value="grass">Grass</option>
  </select>
  <p><input type="button" value="Calulate" onclick="calcWeakness()"></p>


  <p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! my friend told me it was because the function wasn't being called, i guess he was right but i couldn't get my head around it.   
Had to basically create a new func to be called since the original func didn't actually send anything to the HTML.  
(at least i think that's what happened here)

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you were calling a function, which you haven't defined. That's good you got your help!